# asp.net partial postback with update panels

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to have an update panel show when i click on a button. Right now it makes a postback of the whole page and it takes a long time to get all the information as the first time. I am trying to speed up that time and would like to know if there was a way to click the button show a panel over top of the page with the rest of the page grayed out and not postback. If I set onClientClick="return false" then the update panel never shows.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="DetailButton" runat="server" CommandName="detail" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' 
      ImageUrl="~/Images/detailbutton_export.png" onmouseover="this.src='/Images/detailbutton2_export.png'" 
      onmouseout="this.src='/Images/detailbutton_export.png'" />
```

and on the code behind

```
else if ((string)e.CommandName == "detail")
{
  // Show the toast of information.
  //ResetApprovalDetailFields();
  PopulateApprovalDetailByWebUserId(webUserId,int.Parse((string)e.CommandArgument) 
  ApprovalDetailPanel.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: 1) we need to see code to truly help you, and 2) if the button triggering the update panel's refresh is outside of the update panel's content, you need to list it in the `<Triggers>` element (or do so programmatically, if you are using dynamic controls). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: also, remove the `onClientClick` from the button.

Comment: Code has been added

Comment: that's the code for the image button. show the update panel portion.

Comment: I have 2 update panels. One has the button in it and the other is what becomes visible when button is clicked